# Parsing a Json response using Jayway JsonPath

Tags: java, json, parsing, jsonpath, jayway

i have the below Json structure,

```
{
  "MyData": {
    "Type": "ABC",
    "Id": "567",
    "Number": "888"
  },
  "RefId": "9999",
  "DataValues": [
    {
      "NumberList": [
        "7777777"
      ],
      "NumberId": "888888888",
      "Phone": "0000000",
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is my code to parse the Json to fetch the value in NumberList,

```
String jsonResponse = "{  \"MyData\": {\"Type\": \"ABC\",\"Id\": \"567\",\"Number\": \"888\"},\"RefId\": \"9999\",\"DataValues\": [{\"NumberList\": [\"7777777\"],\"NumberId\": \"888888888\",\"Phone\": \"0000000\" }]}";
        List<Map<String, Object>> responseValue = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse(jsonResponse).read("NumberList");
        String number = responseValue.get(0).get("NumberList").toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
System.out.println("number --> " + number);
```

The output is
number --> "7777777"

Double inverted quotes are present in the output

How to get the correct output here, need just the value 7777777

With restassured jsonPath, i get the correct output for below code.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> responseValue = new io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath(jsonResponse).get("NumberList");
        String number = responseValue.get(0).get("NumberList").toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
```

But i dont want to use rest assured jsonPath.

How to get the correct output with jayway JsonPath ??

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you may mean

```java
JsonPath.parse(jsonResponse).read("DataValues")
```

but not

```java
JsonPath.parse(jsonResponse).read("NumberList")
```

Second, it's better to use net.minidev.json.JSONArray.get() instead of toString() like this.

```java
String jsonResponse = "{  
                           \"MyData\": {
                               \"Type\": \"ABC\",
                               \"Id\": \"567\",
                               \"Number\": \"888\"
                           },
                           \"RefId\": \"9999\",
                           \"DataValues\": [{
                               \"NumberList\": [\"7777777\"],
                               \"NumberId\": \"888888888\",
                               \"Phone\": \"0000000\" 
                           }]
                       }";
// Get "DataValues" in json
List<Map<String, Object>> responseValue = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse(jsonResponse).read("DataValues");
// Get "NumberList" in json. Note that "DataValues" is an array
net.minidev.json.JSONArray jsonArray = (net.minidev.json.JSONArray) responseValue.get(0).get("NumberList");
// Get the first element in "NumberList"
String number = (String) jsonArray.get(0);
System.out.println("number --> " + number);
```

The output is

> number --> 7777777

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).